# PascalABC вставка элемента в начало списка

Tags: pascal, списки

Есть у меня код и последнее что нужно сделать это добавить в однонаправленный список элемент в начало списка. В конец есть везде, я думал,  что в начало также получится но не смог написать. Помогите пожалуйста. 
Вот основные переменные моей программы:

```
type
TData = Integer;
TPElem = ^TElem;
TElem = record
Data : TData;
PNext : TPElem;
end;
TDList = record
PFirst, PLast : TPElem;
end;
```

Comment: "В конец есть везде я думал" - я тоже долго думал, глядя на эту фразу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде ничего особенного нет в этой вставке:

```
выделить память под NewHead (New)
NewHead^.PNext := DList.PFirst;
DList.PFirst := NewHead;
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, для меня сложная тема некоторое дается легко, а некоторое нет, запутываюсь.

Comment: @ДенисЛобанов Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 1):

```
newElem.PNext := list.PFirst;
list.PFirst := newElem;
```